# How to randomly assign 2 character codes in Java

Tags: java

I have two groups that can be assigned to a participant in my program that are denoted in an enum as "RG" and "NP". I want to assign these groups randomly. Is there a way to do this in java?

For example, when I randomly generated the participant's ID (which I'm currently just writing out to a file), I did this:

```
Random rndbid = new Random();
int msDBID = 10 + rndbid.nextInt(90);
stringB.append(String.valueOf(msDBID));
stringB.append("\t");
```

Is there something similar to that, that would enable me to do the same thing but instead of randomly generating an int, it would randomly generate either a "RG" or "NP"?

Please let me know if you need clarification. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I am very new to Java, so please be as explanatory as possible! I am learning as I go. Thanks!!

Comment: Generate a random number 0/1. If 0 => RG, else => NP.

Comment: `String[] possiblities = new String[]{"RG", "NP"}; possibilities[(new Random()).nextInt(2)];` Works with any number of possible strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method :

```
public String flip(){
    Random randomNum = new Random();
    int result = randomNum.nextInt(2);
    if(result == 0){
        return "RG";
    } else {
        return "NP";
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer for the same.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon on the third line. Too minor for me to edit.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the same,

Comment: Why you end your comments with `the same` what does it mean?

Comment: I'm usually against terseness for its own sake, but in this case I think `return random.nextBoolean() ? "RG" : "NP";` would be just as readable. And it would save 5 lines.

Answer (score 5):

You can make a static method in your enum to generate random instances. This will scale if you decide to add more enum values.

```
public enum MyEnum {
    RG,
    NP;

    public static MyEnum getRandom(Random random) {
        MyEnum[] allMyEnums = MyEnum.values();
        int randomEnumIndex = random.nextInt(allMyEnums.length);
        return allMyEnums[randomEnumIndex];
    }
}
```

Since you mentioned you are new to Java, here's a basic rundown. In Java, an `enum` can have methods associated with it. In this case, I added a static method (which would be called like `MyEnum.getRandom(random)`) . This method doesn't have to be part of the enum, but it might be convenient there.

The `.values()` method of an enum will return an array containing all of the enum's values, in order. I put this in the variable `allMyEnums`. So, `allMyEnums[x]` will return the xth indexed enum. In this case `allMyEnums[0]` would be RG and `allMyEnums[1]` would be NP. Inside `allMyEnums`, I am returning a random integer between 0 and the number of values there are (the array length). This will end up picking an enum randomly.

Answer (score 3):

Use `random.nextInt()` to select from among the enum values.

```
Random r = new Random();
Group group = Groups.values()[r.nextInt(Groups.values().length];
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate an int which is either 0 or 1. Map the 0 to RG and the 1 to NP. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Random` to only ever generate `0` or `1`, and then use that to generate one string or the other:

```
rndbid.nextInt(2) == 0 ? "RG" : "NP"; // original answer
rndbid.nextBoolean() ? "RG" : "NP"; // even better
```

Comment: Why not just use `nextBoolean()`?

Comment: @JustACluelessNewbie: Definitely.